# Add parent url to simple product screen

Tags: magento2, products, simple-product, product-linking

I need to add a block on a simple product page which contains a url link to the parent if it exists. Block would be positioned under the short description.

I have seen lots of code examples (some are functions with a protected variable, others straight php code) to get the parent id but no explanation as to which file they should be added to or how they should be called.

Comment: Please add more information on requirement and post what you've tried ?

Comment: Magento 2.2.6 Porto Theme.

Comment: Magento 2.2.6 Porto Theme. example link https://lilleytileandstone.co.uk/schluter-reno-t-a-transition-profile-a-aluminium-h-9mm-w-14mm-l-2-5-mtrs.html I have added a link within the short description for what I need. I have tried calling a phtml file into one of the tabs for test purposes using {{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Smartwave_Porto::config-link.phtml"}} Test only please ignore</p> This calls the phtml file sucessfully but the code does not work. , either crashing the screen or showing a generic php error.

Comment: A bit green i'm afraid!